# How can I use val from secondary constructor?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm making my custom view. Before I add constructor contain `defStyleRes`, the original constructor is primary constructor. so I can use `attrs` at `init`. How can I use it now?

```java
class StoreTotalPanel : RelativeLayout {
    @JvmOverloads
    constructor(
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
        defStyleAttr: Int = 0)
            : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    constructor(
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet?,
        defStyleAttr: Int,
        defStyleRes: Int)
            : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)

    init {
        LayoutInflater.from(context)
            .inflate(layout.panel_store_total, this, true)

        attrs?.let { // <- Here is error
            val typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(it, R.styleable.custom_card_view)
            val myString = typedArray.getString(R.styleable.custom_card_view_command)
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because `init` relies on the primary constructor. Since there is none, it fails to find `attrs`. The solution is to replace `init` with your own function, which is called by both secondary connstructors:

```
class StoreTotalPanel : RelativeLayout {

    @JvmOverloads
    constructor(
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
        defStyleAttr: Int = 0
    ) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
        init(context, attrs)
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    constructor(
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet?,
        defStyleAttr: Int,
        defStyleRes: Int
    ) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes) {
        init(context, attrs)
    }


    private fun init(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) {
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(layout.panel_store_total, this, true)

        attrs?.let {
            val typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(it, R.styleable.custom_card_view)
            val myString = typedArray.getString(R.styleable.custom_card_view_command)
        }
    }
}
```

Be aware that `inflate()` returns a view which you do not use yet; the layout will be empty with this code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create a val on constructor itself?

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    constructor(
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet?,
        defStyleAttr: Int,
        private val defStyleRes: Int)
            : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)
```

Comment: That code will say `'val' on secondary constructor parameter is not allowed`